# typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;?

Tags: c, struct

Estoy leyendo un libro de patrones de diseño y utilizan el typedef de la siguiente manera. Cual sería la función en este caso?

```
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;  

struct MyStruct {
  char var_1 ;
char var_2 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

'typedef' se utiliza para definir un alias. Por ejemplo:

```
typedef int tipo;
```

significa que podemos usar 'tipo' como 'int' indistintamente. De modo que

```
tipo x;
```

equivale a crear una variable 'int' llamada x.

Por lo tanto la sentencia

```
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
```

significa que 'MyStruct' equivale a 'struct MyStruct'.

De ese modo en lugar de definir variables como

```
struct MyStruct a;
```

podremos hacerlo del modo abreviado

```
MyStruct a;
```

De todos modos la forma más habitual de combinar 'typedef' y 'struct' es la siguiente:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    char var_1;
    char var_2;
} MyStruct;
```

Fíjate que lo que hace es definir el 'struct MyStruct {...}' además de usar 'typedef' para indicar que 'struct MyStruct' equivale a simplemente 'MyStruct'. Es equivalente al código de tu pregunta pero más compacto.